# Regex in Notepad++ : How to get last part of URLs?

Tags: regex, url, notepad++

I have some URL like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/at/hello-everybody-mn0000000003
http://www.mywebsite.com/am/I-dont-care-mw0000322930
http://www.mywebsite.com/ccc/mood/I-love-you-d5207
```

How to get the last part which removed the last word?

```
hello-everybody
I-dont-care
I-love-you
```

Comment: @Raptor, I don't know about regex. I only know ^.*\/ to match from beginning to "/"

Comment: Learn regex in regex101.com

Comment: `http://www.mywebsite.com/.*/(.+)-\S+$` - part in parentheses is what you need

Comment: @fred-ii-, this is not a duplicate of that question.  This has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: @Godisgood OP wasn't responding to any of my (now deleted) comments. Communication is good too ;) reopened. OP did originally tag as php.

Comment: Don't ask the same question more than once, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the below lookahead based regex.

```
[^\/]+?(?=-[^-\/]+$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gX3sD2/3)

Comment: Hi, How to extract them ?

Comment: use this `.*?([^\/]+?)-[^-\/]+$` regex and then replace the matched chars by `\1` see https://regex101.com/r/gX3sD2/4

Answer (score 0):

hope it can help you!

```
$str = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/at/hello-everybody-mn0000000003';
$str = preg_replace('@http://www.mywebsite.com/(.*)/@','',$str);
$str = substr($str,0,strrpos($str,'-'));
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not PHP. I removed PHP tag.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is the furthest I can get you:

```
(?!\/)(?:.(?!\/))+(?=-)
```

This is what it would match:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/at/hello-everybody-mn0000000003   Matches: hello-everybody
http://www.mywebsite.com/am/I-dont-care-mw0000322930       Matches: I-dont-care
http://www.mywebsite.com/ccc/mood/I-love-you-d5207         Matches: I-love-you
```

Comment: This is even simpler: `/[\w-]+(?=-)/`.

Comment: Oh? Why didn't you post an answer then? Lol.

Comment: Because this question is closed and I can't, duh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegEx: `/[\w-]+(?=-)/`.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/gX3sD2/1

Comment: Great ! It worked. However, can you tell me how to extract them ?